# Georg Cantors 5th paper

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I was wondering if anyone knows a website where i can find an english translation of the original works by Georg Cantor, if possible this would be extremely helpful, i can only seem to find non translated versions. Mainly i'm interested in his contributions to set theory.

Comment: Yes If it is even possible to obtain :).

Comment: I am not aware of any translation of Cantor's collected works into English in print, let alone on line. But perhaps someone on MSE can correct me about that.

Comment: @rob Arthan I think i've found a copy if you are interested - https://ia600202.us.archive.org/29/items/contributionstof00cant/contributionstof00cant.pdf